# Can log4net output Json?

Tags: c#, json, wpf, log4net

I've seen a couple extensions for log4net that claim to create json to the log file, but the format is never valid json, meaning the collection is not in an array and not coma separated. Am I using it wrong or is there just no way to use log4net with json?

```
<appender name="SessionFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <file value="Session.log" />
  <appendToFile value="false" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type='log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json'>
    <decorator type='log4net.Layout.Decorators.StandardTypesDecorator, log4net.Ext.Json' />
    <default />
    <remove value='message' />
    <member value='message:messageobject' />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Output is:

```
{"date":"2017-01-29T13:45:50.7345813-05:00","level":"DEBUG","appname":"MyApp.vshost.exe","logger":"MainWindow","thread":"9","ndc":"(null)","message":"Loading new UI instance"}
{"date":"2017-01-29T13:45:50.7380842-05:00","level":"DEBUG","appname":"MyApp.vshost.exe","logger":"MainWindow","thread":"9","ndc":"(null)","message":"Loading internal localization file"}
{"date":"2017-01-29T13:45:50.7510970-05:00","level":"DEBUG","appname":"MyApp.vshost.exe","logger":"MainWindow","thread":"9","ndc":"(null)","message":"Initializing UI"}
```

which is close, but not really valid json.

Comment: Your output seems like valid JSON Lines format: http://jsonlines.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is basic enough, I wrote my own `Appender` that stored data in a collection, then serialized the collection with Json.net as needed. This also gives me the ability to view the log in the app and bind to it aswell so added bonus.

```
public class CollectionAppender : AppenderSkeleton
{
    public static ObservableCollection<LogItem> logData = new ObservableCollection<LogItem>();
    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        logData.Add(new LogItem(loggingEvent));
    }
}

public class LogItem
{
    public string Logger { get; private set; }
    public string Level { get; private set; }
    public string Message { get; private set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; private set; }
    public Exception ExceptionData { get; private set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeExceptionData() //This keeps things tidy when using Json.net for non exemption entries.
    {
        return ExceptionData != null;
    }

    public LogItem(LoggingEvent data)
    {
        Logger = data.LoggerName;
        Level = data.Level.DisplayName;
        Message = data.RenderedMessage;
        Timestamp = data.TimeStamp;
        ExceptionData = data.ExceptionObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a nice solution! Is log4net still actively maintained, it would be nice to have it in there - maybe wroth a contrib?

Comment: I use this approach in testing scenarios. If that is all you need, simple enough.

Answer (score 13):

download [log4net.Ext.Json nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net.Ext.Json)

add following config settings to app.config/web.config files

```
<log4net>
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="logs\log-file-name.json" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
  <PreserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <dateTimeStrategy 
  type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender+UniversalDateTime" />

  <!--text formatted log4net logging-->
  <!--<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    --><!--check conversion patterns from 
   https://logging.apache.org/log4net/--><!--
    --><!--<conversionPattern value="%utcdate{ABSOLUTE} UTC %c{1} - %m%n" 
  />--><!--
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - 
  %message%newline" />
  </layout>-->

  <!--json formatted log4net logging-->
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json">
    <decorator type="log4net.Layout.Decorators.StandardTypesDecorator, 
  log4net.Ext.Json" />
    <member value="date:date" />
    <member value="level:level" />
    <member value="logger:logger" />
    <member value="message:messageObject" />
    <member value="exception:exception" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <!--Options are "ALL", "DEBUG", "INFO", "WARN", "ERROR", "FATAL" and 
"OFF".-->
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
</root>
</log4net>
```

here is a sample call with ninject

```
Kernel = new StandardKernel(); 
Kernel.Bind<ILog>().ToMethod(c => 
LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(YourClassName))).InSingletonScope();
var log = Kernel.Get<ILog>();
log.debug("testing log4net json");
```

Answer (score 2):

It outputs each line as separate JSON record, as it does with 1 line logs.
You can take line by line and parse, or you can add your surrounding [] and a comman after each } and that would do it.

Comment: If I still have to iterate and re-parse a file after the fact then it kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Your are right @Wobbles, but its kind of hard even for them since logs open-write-close streams so i think it will be tricky to maintain the json format, unless the file is in memory and get overridden each time a record is written.

Comment: didn't consider that, ill see if there is a way to directly serialize the ILog collection then as needed

Comment: If you didnt find a solution and you are using it as it is in c# or JS, then i suggect you add [ and ] and replace all ( } ) with ( }, ) and it will work with only one parse, heavy but will do the trick. @Wobbles

Comment: It could be achieved on appender level. log4net.Ext.Json works as a layout for individual log events. If you go for string replacement as @MoustafaS recommended, please put coma before every new line instead of `}` because the graph can be nested or the data may contain `}` while new lines are escaped by default.